# How to add assembly to web.config using C# asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, assemblies

I want to click a button in a webform page to add an assembly to the web.config file.

How can I do that?

```
<assemblies>

<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>

</assemblies>
```

Comment: why would you want to do that? assembly references tend to be known at compile time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can manipulate that section of the web.config via the [AssemblyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.assemblycollection.aspx)  .